# Stumbleupon.com technology

Tags: frameworks, stumbleupon

I've looked all over the web and stackoverflow and can't find anyone talking about stubleupon.com's lineup. Including: framework, language, database, etc. Does anyone have any idea or at least a guess?  - thanks

Comment: You can build powerful web sites with LAMP technology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really see such things from the outside. However, by hoovering over the "Join for free" button, you see a `php` link (the target of the button is `signup.php`, so the language probably is php (You can't be sure as it depends entirely on the configuration of the server).

Comment: i'm sorry if this sounds elementary but what do you mean a "php link" you mean other links look different?

Comment: if you mouse over a link, the target is `something.php`. If they were using REST-like links (like `page.com/signup/`) you'd had no way of seeing it from the outside.